# como puedo guardar un formulario en una pagina diferente?

Tags: javascript, asp

soy novata en esto de la programacion pero en la prepa me estan pidiendo que haga un formulario sencillo que al dar click en un boton, guarde los registros del formulario en una pagina diferente para visualizarlos cuando sea
ayuda porfis ya vi videos, tutoriales pero no entiendo muy bien
este es el ejemplo de formulario que estoy usando:

```
         <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Formulario sencillo</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function recibir() {
  var nomId=document.getElementById("nombre").value;
  var apeName=document.getElementsByName("apellido")[0].value;
  document.getElementById("escribir").innerHTML=" \ Tu nombre es: "+nomId+" \
   <br>Tu apellido es: "+apeName;
  }
function borrar() {
   document.getElementById("escribir").innerHTML=" " ;
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h3>Formulario sencillo</h3>
<form id="form_js">
  <p><input type="text" name="nombre"  id="nombre" placeholder="Escribe tu nombre" size="20" autofocus ></p>
  <p><input type="text" name="apellido" placeholder="Escribe tu apellido" size="30"></p>
  <p><input type="button"  onclick="recibir()" value="Enviar"></p>
</form>
<br/>
<div id="escribir"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

una disculpa si no es correcto
lo que quiero que haga es que esos datos, los guarde en una pagina diferente

Comment: Muestra algo de codigo para que te podamos ayudar. Ademas, tu pregunta tiene que se concisa y demostrar que hay esfuerzo de tu parte para conseguir la solucion. Tu pregunta es muy abierta.

Comment: si, muchas gracias, recien inicio en esto de programar, gracias por darme tips :D!!

Comment: ¿Realmente estás utilizando ASP?

Comment: Si:(, una disculpa si no es correcto ,es como me lo piden en la prepa:(